# Solving Matrix Equations including nested Hadamard products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

How can we solve the following equation for B?

$$yl^T \odot D = [(AB \odot D)ll^T]\odot D $$

$y_{n*1}$, $l_{d*1}$ are vectors, $A_{n*k}$, $B_{k*d}$, $D_{n*d}$ are full rank non-square matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $d > 1$, the equation does not have a unique solution because there are matrices $M$ for which $M(ll^T) = 0$.  That said, we can rewrite the equation as follows.

If we [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) both sides of the equation, we end up with the equivalent
$$
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T \odot D) = \operatorname{vec}([(AB \odot D)ll^T]\odot D)\\
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T \odot D) = 
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D))
\operatorname{vec}((AB \odot D)ll^T)\\
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T \odot D) = 
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D))
(ll^T \otimes I)
\operatorname{vec}(AB \odot D)\\
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T \odot D) = 
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D))
(ll^T \otimes I)
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D)) \operatorname{vec}(AB)\\
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T \odot D) = 
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D))
(ll^T \otimes I)
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B).
$$

If the entries of $D$ are all non-zero, we could "Hadamard divide" by the entries of $D$ (i.e. undo $\odot D$  on both sides) in order to simplify the equation to get
$$
yl^T  = (AB \odot D)ll^T \implies\\
\operatorname{vec}(yl^T) = 
(ll^T \otimes I)
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B).
$$
Because the map $v \mapsto vl^T$ is invertible as well, this can be further simplified to
$$
y  = (AB \odot D)l \implies\\
y = 
(l^T \otimes I)
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D)) (I \otimes A)\operatorname{vec}(B).
$$

---

If we have a rank-decomposition of $D$, we could remove the Hadamard product by noting that
$$
D = \sum_{j=1}^r u_j v_j^T \implies D \odot M = \sum_{j=1}^r  \operatorname{diag}(u_j) M \operatorname{diag}(v_j).
$$
With that, we have
$$
y  = (AB \odot D)l \implies
y = \sum_{j=1}^r \operatorname{diag}(u_j) AB \operatorname{diag}(v_j) l.
$$

Comment: Thank you, but how can we solve for $B$ instead of $y$? We have to use the pseudoinverse I guess?

Comment: @JohnnieThick Yes, that's the best you can do. As I said, there is no unique solution, so it correspondingly holds that $(l \otimes I)
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(D)) (I \otimes A)$ will not be invertible.

Comment: @JohnnieThick I've written out a formula for the solution via the pseudoinverse; see the latest edit.

Comment: @JohnnieThick Actually, there are no simplifications that can be applied here; it just comes down to computing the pseudoinverse directly.

Comment: thank you very much. I guess we could also have $B=Q^+yR^+$ where $Q=\sum_{j=1}^r \operatorname{diag}(u_j) A$ and $R=\operatorname{diag}(v_j) l$?

Comment: @JohnnieThick no, that's not correct. Note that for $r > 1$,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^r \operatorname{diag}(u_j) AB \operatorname{diag}(v_j) l \neq 
\left(\sum_{j=1}^r \operatorname{diag}(u_j) A\right) B \left(\sum_{j=1}^r\operatorname{diag}(v_j) l\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks sorry. I did not realise the sum continues, though it is obvious due to $u_j$